# Rational subsets of a monoid

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

In "Rational Set of Commutative Monoid", S. Eilenberg and M.P. Schützenberger define the class of rational subsets of a monoid $M$ as the least class $F$ of subsets of $M$ such that satisfy the following properties:

1. the empty set is in $F$;
2. Each single element set is in $F$;
3. If $X, Y$ are in $F$, then $X \cup Y$ is in $F$;
4. If $X, Y$ are in $F$, then $XY$ is in $F$;
5. If $X$ is in $F$, then $X^*$ is in $F$.

In 4. $XY = \{xy \mid  x \in X \text{ and } y \in Y \}$, what is this product? concatenation product?

In the following link, there is a complete paper 
http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Mps/Travaux/A/1969-3RationalSetsCommutativeMonoids.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product is the monoid product. A monoid is a set equipped with an operation (which we can call *product*) satisfying certain axioms. The classical monoid we use in formal languages is $\Sigma^*$ (for some alphabet $\Sigma$), in which case the monoid product is indeed concatenation. But this is not the only possibility: for example, every group is a monoid, since the monoid axioms are a subset of the group axioms.

Comment: X, Y are monoids?

Comment: They are subsets of the monoid M.

Comment: For example, I consider the monid M = (N, +), where N is the set of natual number, and + is the "traditional" addiction. For X, Y $\subset$, XY = {x+y | x $\in$ X and y $\in$ Y }. Is it right?

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: ... and $X^*$ is the submonoid of $M$ generated by $X$.